# hitting javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated even imported cert

Tags: java, ssl, https, certificate, websphere

Good day,

As my understanding, if an application needs to connect to a https web service, I have to download the cert from the URL and import the cert to WAS Console. This is working fine for me.

Until today, the application has to call a new https URL. Same way, I download the cert and import the cert into WAS Console, but application hitting `peer not authenticated` error.

After my checking, this URL is using CA cert, not the self-sign cert that I imported usually. May I know is it the way to import CA cert into WAS Console different?

Based on the screen shot below, I imported total 3 cents.

[image]

Am I doing the correct way? or for CA cert URL, I need to ask cert from the URL owner? instead of downloading myself.

Will it be caused by protocol issue? I already set the WAS setting protocol to `SSL_TLSv2`

Kindly advise.

Comment: Could you post the entire stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

WebSphere has a "retrieve signer from port" function in the SSL Certificate Management UI. That will connect to the host/port you instruct it to and find the root, self-signed issuer (if the server sends it, it's not required) and add it as trusted.

If the server does not send its root, self-signed issuer, you can always look at the last certificate it provides in the chain and add it manually.

Comment: Yes, I did the second way you mention. I download the last certificate in the chain and add in manually. It still not working. Then I tried download all the certificate in the chain, and add in manually, still the same error. Do you have any idea?